# How do you change the default subdrectories in an Eclipe ADT project?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I would like to be able to change the default subdirectories created as part of an Eclipse ADT project.  That is, instead of "res" and "bin" I would like to have something else.

With most kinds of Eclipse projects it seems pretty straightforward -- there are a few places where you go to change different core subdirectories, you go there and change them, and that's pretty much that.

With the ADT plugin for Eclipse, it seems that if you refactor "res" to "resources" for example a new folder called "res" gets automatically added anyway.  The same seems to be true for "bin" and "gen."

Where do I start to look to learn more about what causes this automated behavior and how to change it?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you can, as they are strictly defined by Android

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html

Why do you want to change the names?

Comment: Thanks for the links.  "res" is a runtime constant but the resources are zipped up and delivered via the resources.ap_ archive.  It seems logical therefore that the source directory for the zip operation could be anything.  There is no technical necessity to change the names.  I want to because I should be able to :) and I am curious to know more about how the ADT does its housekeeping.